# Streaming videos from dropbox so they can be displayed on a web page

Tags: php, video-streaming

I'm Using PHP and MYSQL to output videos on to a web page. The web page will not be created in WordPress. I have about 10 videos stored on my Dropbox account. How do I stream videos from Dropbox onto a web page? I want users to be able to watch videos on my web page. Thank you for your time and help.

This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Streaming videos from dropbox</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once('connection.php');

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
        $id=intval($_GET['id']); 

         $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * dropbox_video WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result ) > 0) {
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //loop vdeo. The row store dropbox URL      
echo '<iframe style="max-width:100%" allowfullscreen="true" src="'.$row["dropbox_video"].'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>';


        }
        else{
            echo 'No data Found';

        }

    }




      ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you google this ? any way [this](http://lockergnome.com/2012/06/26/how-use-dropbox-host-stream-videos/) might help. According to the article you need to use HTML5 video tag. So drop the iframe and try with the video tag.

Comment: I tried the html5 player but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Do you get any error when you try to stream or do you get a blank screen.

Comment: The error is saying "No video with supported format and MIME type found".